# How do I float right only when screen is smaller but float left when screen is bigger?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have an effect where the picture is on left side of text, but when the screen is smaller, the text is on top and img is below.

Currently, I have the former, but when the screen size reduces, the img goes on top and text is on bottom. How do I reverse this?

Here is my code (theres a div for img and one for the description text):

```html
<div class="container productwrap shadow-lg mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 p-2 m-3 border">
            <img src="../Pictures/snacks3.jpeg" alt="snacks2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 p-2 my-3 border rounded">
            <p class="newarrival text-center pt-3 font-weight-bold">Trendy Snacks</p>
            <h2 style="display: inline-block" class="p-3 ml-2 border rounded">Brown Sugar Yogourt</h2>
            <span class="badge badge-success align-top m-1">NEW!</span>
            <p class="lead font-weight-bold text-warning m-4">CAD $9,99</p>
            <p class="m-4"><strong>Unit: </strong>2 x 100g</p>
            <p class="m-4"><strong>Availability: </strong>In Stock</p>
            <label for="qty" class="ml-4"><strong>Quantity:</strong>
                <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="small w-25 text-right" value="1">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" href="#" role="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            </label>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-2 mr-3 rounded-pill" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreinfo">More info</button>
                <div id="moreinfo" class="collapse text-wrap">
                This delicacy instills the careful mix of brown sugar and yogourt. Its rich nutriments will revitalize your spirit and set you ready for your day.
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using float-right/left but it doesn't budge at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to have an effect where the picture is on right side of text, but when the screen is smaller, the text is on top and img is below. Currently, I have the former ...

I'm not seeing you have the former. On bigger screens, the picture is on the left side of text...

If you switch the order of the picture structure and your text structure, you achieve both:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5m2z4s90/4/

#### Updates:

You can use [order utilities class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#order) to achieve what you want:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 order-2 order-md-1">
            <img />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 order-1 order-md-2">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On small screens, the image is 2nd item so it will appear at the bottom. On medium break point and up, you switch it back so that the image will appear on the left of the row.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5m2z4s90/9/

Comment: I''m sorry I made a mistake, I meant I want the picture to be on the LEFT side usually, and then on bottom when the screen is smaller...

Comment: It worked, you are a saint! I had completely forgot about orders

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Grid and align how you want to align in default. Then use a media query and when the view gets smaller just change the div size and order of grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

A common more complex responsive design technique is to use 'Media Queries' in CSS.

To start, align the items as you like them by default. Then, choose a limit for your resizing (ex: 'width less than 600px'). Once you have that set, you can begin a media query like so:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  *selector* {
    *change you want to make when screen is smaller than 600px*;
  }
}
```

Doing this will cause the changes to the CSS rules to automatically apply whenever the width of the screen is less than 600px, but it should also revert back to the default values whenever the screen increases in size again.

Media Queries can get a lot more complex and involved than in this example, but they are incredibly useful once you get used to them. I strongly suggest reading into them some.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of media query but I have no idea how I can change the div to be on the right inside the media query. I was thinking to float-right the image inside the media query, but it doesn't budge.

Comment: Could you post your code again? As well as the stylesheet? Solely because I'm interested at this point...